# How to show all index data from Codeigniter and mongodb?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the code to show `TripUUID`. But it showed just one data. The code is as follows:

```
function list_of_tripreview(){

        $data = $this->data;
        $arr = [];

$data['list_of_tripreview'] = $this->cms_model->list_of_tripreview();
$TripUUID       = $data['list_of_tripreview'][0]['TripUUID'];
echo json_encode($TripUUID);
```

This code gives the output `TripUUID` on index `0`. How do I revise this program to show all index data without [`0`]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`foreach loop`**

```
$data['list_of_tripreview'] = $this->cms_model->list_of_tripreview();
$datas = $data['list_of_tripreview'];
//$TripUUID = $data['list_of_tripreview'][0]['TripUUID'];

foreach($datas as $key => $item){
    echo $item['TripUUID'].'<br>';
}
```